# how to send api_key and api_secret arguments in jquery post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post, jsonp

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://apius.faceplusplus.com/detection/detect',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: '{ "comment" }',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(responseData) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
        }
    });
```

I am sending a post request to above which requires `api_key` and `api_secret` parameters for authentication. I tried sending value of this 2 paramenters like this in above request:

```
headers: 
{
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode('value of api key here' + ":" + 'value of api secret here') 
},
```

But when I execute the request it says 400 BAD REQUEST and when I hit the url in browser it shows

> {
>       "error": "MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key", 
>       "error_code": 1004
>   }

Please suggest me a solution. I am stuck for long time.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the key/value pairs in the data object of the ajax request, like this:

```
data: '{ "api_key": "thekeyhere", "api_secret": "thesecrethere" }'
```

Comment: it is not working. .I made it work using api's js function I just added 1 line above this code to call api's js function  which asks api key and secret and used above code to resolve cross domain problem....now I am getting ready state 4 and staus 200...but I think its json response parsing error..plz suggest how to resolve this